# ActiveRendering - Drawing on Buffer not working

Tags: java, drawing, pong

I am creating a pong game. I have fininshed the ball and paddle classes, the animator and everything else related. However when I open my created program only 1 paddle shows, while the other paddle and the ball do not show. If I change the way I draw things, the ball will show and the other 2 paddles don't. So it only draws 1 thing, whatever comes first. Here is the code for part which paints to the buffer.

```
public void renderlojen(){ // render game function
        if(pamja==null){
            pamja=createImage(GJERESIA,LARTESIA); // Image - serves as buffer

        }

        g =(Graphics2D) pamja.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, GJERESIA, LARTESIA);

        doreza1.vizatodorezen(g); // paddle1
        doreza2.vizatodorezen(g); // paddle2
        topi1.vizatotopin(g); // ball

        g.dispose();
    }

public void updatolojen(){  // update game function
        topi1.leviztopin();
        doreza1.levizdorezen();
        doreza2.levizdorezen();
    }

public void pikturolojen(){ // draw from buffer to screen
        if (pamja!=null){
            g=(Graphics2D)this.getGraphics();
            g.drawImage(pamja, 0, 0, null);
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
            g.dispose();
            System.out.println(doreza1.merrX());
            System.out.println(doreza2.merrX());
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Ska pamje");

    }

public void vizatotopin(Graphics2D g2d){ // draw the ball code
        topiforma =new Ellipse2D.Float(pozicioniX,pozicioniY,2*rrezja,2*rrezja);
        g2d.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g2d.fill(topiforma);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

public void vizatodorezen (Graphics2D g2d){ // draw paddle code
        drejtkendeshforma = new Rectangle2D.Float(pozicioniX,pozicioniY,GJERESIA,LARTESIA);
        g2d.setColor(ngjyra);
        g2d.fill(drejtkendeshforma);
        g2d.dispose();
    }
```

Comment: What do the individual drawing methods do? (`X.vizatodorezen(Graphics)`, I presume)

Comment: The ball one draws a oval, with the ball's current position x,y and the 2*radius width and height. The paddle one draws a rect at x,y with the specified width and height.

Comment: @kiheru But I am suprised because If I put the ball to be drawn first, then the paddles do not get drawn... If I put the paddle first before the ball in the code, only 1 paddle gets drawn. So whoever comes first, gets drawn.

Comment: I asked because there are a couple of possibilities: like if some of the drawing code throws an exception so that the other methods do not get called, or if a method changes the coordinates of the graphics (like by calling `translate()`) so that the other objects would end up off screen.

Comment: @kiheru alright I am adding the drawing code for the paddle and the ball in here, so you can check it out...

Comment: @kiheru Seems like that g2d.dispose() ruins everything. You were right, the problem was in that code.... respond so I can give you the correct answer

Comment: Do not call `Graphics.dispose()` for graphics objects in the drawing methods.

Comment: @kiheru beat you in 13 sec :P ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is calling `Graphics.dispose()` in the rendering methods of the game objects. Drawing to the `Graphics` is not valid after that, so only the first object gets drawn.

In general, call `Graphics.dispose()` only in the same method where you created it. Not in methods that receive one as a parameter.